# How do I remove all ink from a Microsoft Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have made LOTS of ink (digital pen) annotations on a Microsoft Word document.  Now I want to delete them all.

Circling all the ink annotations on a single page is challenging -- let alone on multiple pages. How can I clear all the ink annotations from my document?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the **File** menu.
2. In the blue bar on the left, select **Info**.
3. In the gray pane in the center, select the drop-down under **Check for Issues** and select **Inspect Document**
4. In the Document Inspector window, check the "Ink" option.
5. Click **Inspect**
6. Scroll through to the **Ink** row and click the **Remove All** button.
7. Click **Close**

Note that this option cannot be undone. It is probably best to save the document before doing this in case you make a mistake.

These instructions work both for Microsoft Word and for Microsoft Power Point.